# json_encode - PHP gives uncomplete json string

Tags: php, json, xcache, suhosin

First my Setting: 
PHP 5.3.2 - with Suoshin and xCache
lighttpd/1.4.26

My Code is too much to Post it here. I will discribe it.

File x.php is loading some PHP - Classe, init them, executes some functions -> getting an Result array.

If I print_r this array I get a full result.

But I've I use json_encode, it cuts it every time on the same position. -> json gets invalid.
Example:
print_r-

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [test2] => 2
            [test3] => Array
                (
                    [test4] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

json -

```
{"test1":{"test2":2,"test3":{"te
```

Error Log says the following:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.2582) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 16708 socket: unix:/tmp/php5.socket-1
(mod_fastcgi.c.3382) response already sent out, but backend returned error on socket: unix:/tmp/php5.socket-1 for /x.php?, terminating connection
```

**The Question is how can i track whats the Error? Or anybody knows whats the Problem?**

Comment: What's the position that it "cuts" on?

Comment: Its every time the same position, but nothing special, just normal string, no special chars or utf8 stuff arround the cut.

Comment: Could we see the JSON string? Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a buffering problem. Make sure that your response buffer is flushed before the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the invalid JSON Problem. But the PHP error is still comming ...